# puppeteer-core broke simply by rebuilding my Docker image

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am running puppeteer-core 9.0.0 inside an AWS lambda as a docker image under nodejs:14-x86_64.  It was working for over a year.  I then rebuilt the docker lambda image without making ANY changes and the new image doesn't work.  I get this:

```
        "Error: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Target closed.",
    "    at /var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:208:63",
    "    at new Promise (<anonymous>)",
    "    at CDPSession.send (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:207:16)",
    "    at navigate (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:108:47)",
    "    at FrameManager.navigateFrame (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:91:13)",
    "    at Frame.goto (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:416:41)",
    "    at Page.goto (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:819:53)",
    "    at pdfBuffer (file:///var/task/app.js:111:16)",
    "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)",
    "    at async Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/app.js:310:18)"
```

I can verify that the nodejs:14_x86_64 base image tag was moved to newer versions over the year so the resulting image is not exactly the same.  I also looked inside the good image and the bad image and compared the npm list of package dependencies and those were identical.  So the only difference I can detect is the base image changed.  Therefore, I changed the Dockerfile to be more specific on the base image tag and used exactly what the good image used back when it was built.  Unfortunately, that still failed.

So I was wondering if anybody has any hints/ideas/possibilities as to what could cause the error above?

Dockerfile used that still fails after pinning the exact base image:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14.2023.08.22.07-x86_64 as base
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum -y install amazon-linux-extras
RUN amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
RUN yum -y install cabextract
RUN yum -y install ipa-gothic-fonts xorg-x11-fonts-100dpi xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi xorg-x11-utils xorg-x11-fonts-cyrillic xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 xorg-x11-fonts-misc
RUN yum -y install liberation-mono-fonts liberation-narrow-fonts liberation-sans-fonts liberation-serif-fonts urw-base35*
RUN rpm -i https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mscorefonts2/rpms/msttcore-fonts-installer-2.6-1.noarch.rpm
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
ARG LAMBDA_NAME
COPY lambdas/source/${LAMBDA_NAME} .
RUN npm ci
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

Comment: Can you add the dockerfile ?

Comment: I revised post above with the Dockerfile.  Thanks.